# Did Timrod inspire Dylan before 'Modern Times'?

Tags: song-lyrics, inspiration, bob-dylan

Bob Dylan's album *Modern Times* has many passages famously inspired by (some say plagiarised from) the poetry of Henry Timrod. Do any of Dylan's earlier works also clearly reflect the influence of Timrod?

Comment: I've asked [a meta question](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/questions/193/how-do-we-answer-questions-in-the-negative) related to this one, and questions similar to it.